# SQL: detect rows which cross time boundaries between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Question:**

How can I detect which rows have lastModifiedDate < boundary at 30s/minute < approvedDate
in T-SQL?

**Background:**

We have a regular process (Autonomy's ODBCConnector product) which scans a view in our database, and picks up news articles which have changed since it last ran, based on the lastModifiedDate field.
This happens every thirty seconds, on the minute and at 30s after the minute.

There was a bug in this process, in that one of the operations was to approve these articles, and that did not cause the lastModifiedDate to change, but changed the approvedDate instead.

So, any article which was modified, picked up, and then approved, will not show up.

This will always be true for articles where `approvedDate >= DATEADD(second, 30, lastModifiedDate)` - but that does not pick up all of the articles which still need to be picked up. An article could have a lastModifiedDate of `28/11/2011  15:48:13` and an approvedDate of `28/11/2011  15:48:31` and not be picked up by the process.

NB the approvedDate is not necessarily more recent than the lastModifiedDate

Comment: Does all this mean you need to select all articles that have either a) lastModifiedDate in the last 30 seconds, or b) approvedDate in the last 30 seconds?

Comment: This means that I need all records where the ApprovedDate is a) after the lastModifiedDate and b) there is a 30s marker between them. e.g. lastModified: 00:00:29 approvedDate: 00:00:31 or lastModified: 00:00:29 approvedDate: 00:01:31 should both be included in the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want all records where the approvedDate is in the next 30s block of time relative to the 30s block of time that the lastModifiedDate is in?

```
LastModifiedDate | ApprovedDate | Include In Results?
00:00:00         | 00:00:00     | No
00:00:00         | 00:00:29     | No
00:00:00         | 00:00:30     | Yes
00:00:00         | 00:00:31     | Yes
00:00:00         | 00:01:01     | No?
00:00:29         | 00:00:29     | No
00:00:29         | 00:00:30     | Yes
00:00:29         | 00:00:31     | Yes
00:00:29         | 00:01:01     | No?
```

If so, try this?

```
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(second, 0, ApprovedDate    ) / 30
  =
  DATEDIFF(second, 0, LastModifiedDate) / 30 + 1
```

In `No?` should be `Yes` in the original table I gave, try this?

```
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(second, 0, ApprovedDate    ) / 30
  >
  DATEDIFF(second, 0, LastModifiedDate) / 30
```

Or, perhaps...

```
WHERE
  ApprovedDate
  >=
  DATEADD(second, 30 - DATEDIFF(second, 0, LastModifiedDate) % 30, lastModifiedDate)
```

Comment: @penguat: Some of my use of `%` was bogus.  I've changed it to `/` where appropriate :)

Comment: This doesn't work: Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps I need to cast my columns (DATETIMEs, both of them) to times? (and handle potential different dates)

Comment: Oh, and the "No?"s should be "Yes" - any where they are across at least one time boundary.

Comment: My bad, I'm used to working with SMALLDATETIME.  Just change to `0` to `40000` or `'2010-01-01'`, to give a more recent base to calculate the second offset from.  (This will cover a range of +/- 68years from whatever base date you choose)